# Efficient way of counting specific occurrences during a for loop

Tags: c#, loops, optimization, histogram, data-visualization

I have a loop of about one million values. I want to store just the exponent of each value to display them e.g. in a histogram.

At the moment I'm doing it this way:

```
int histogram[51]; //init all with 0
for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    int exponent = getExponent(getValue(i)); 
    //getExponent(double value) gives the exponent(base 10)
    //getValue(int i) gives the value for loop i
    if(exponent > 25)
        exponent = 25;
    if(exponent < -25)
        exponent = -25;
    histogramm[exponent+25]++;
}
```

Is there a more efficient and elegant way of doing this?
Perhaps without using an array?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a more efficient and elegant way of doing this?

The only more elegant way would be to use `Math.Min` and `Math.Max` but it wouldn't be any more efficient. `histogramm[Math.Max(0,Math.Min(50,exponent+25))]++` is fewer characters but no more performant or elegant in my opinion.

> Perhaps without using an array?

An array is a raw set of values so is the most straightforward way of storing them.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `getExponent` and `getValue` are optimized, the only way to optimize this is to use `Parrallel.For`. I don't think the difference will be significant, but i see it as the only way.

As for the array, it is the best indexed low-level data structure that you can use for storing data.

Use Parallel Library [ `using System.Threading.Tasks;` ]:

```
int[] histogram = new int[51]; //init all with 0

Action<int> work = (i) =>
{
    int exponent = getExponent(getValue(i));
    //getExponent(double value) gives the exponent(base 10)
    //getValue(int i) gives the value for loop i
    if (exponent > 25)
        exponent = 25;
    if (exponent < -25)
        exponent = -25;
    histogram[exponent + 25]++;
};

Parallel.For(0, 1000000, work);
```

Comment: Whoa hold on, that increment isn't thread safe! E: and if it was, then the super high sharing would make it not much faster than single-threaded. Using separate arrays and summing after solves both, but isn't as nice to write.

Comment: Only if the calculations themselves are slow enough to compensate for the parallel overhead will this be an improvement. Bust out a profiler and see if it makes a difference for you.

Answer (score 1):

There's not much to optimize with the conditional and array access. However, if the getExponent function is a time consuming operation, you can cache the results. A lot is really going to depend on what typical data looks like. Profile to see if it helps. Also, someone else mentioned using Parallel. That's worth profiling too as it could make a difference if getValue or getExponent are slow enough to overcome the Parallel and locking overhead.

Important note: Using double is probably a bad idea for a dictionary. But I'm confused by the math going on and conversions from double's to int's.

Either way, the idea here is to cache a calculation. So perhaps you can find a better way if this test proves useful.

```
int[] histogram = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 51).ToArray();
...
Dictionary<double, int> cache = new Dictionary<double, int>(histogram.Length);
...

for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    double value = getValue(i);
    int exponent;
    if(!cache.TryGetValue(value, out exponent))
    {
        exponent = getExponent(value);
        cache[value] = exponent;
    }

    if (exponent > 25)
        exponent = 25;
    else if (exponent < -25)
        exponent = -25;

    histogram[exponent + 25]++;
}
```

Comment: `Enumerable.Repeat(0, 51).ToArray()` - why would anyone ever write that?

Comment: @harold Hah! It's an artifact of some experiments I was trying for optimization (it wasn't always a zero).

Comment: Fair enough, plausible excuse :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using an public property to store your values for you exponent, so can test and check your results.

As for as elegance goes, I would simplify the `if` conditions with actual functions or subroutines, and create additional abstraction with clear and concise naming.